# is the given function differentiable at origin

Tags: complex-analysis

it is given that f(z) = Im(z^2)/(z bar) when zis not equal to 0 and f(z) =0 when z=0

so when i find the limit of f(z) it depends on a parameter m 
so limit doesnot exist uniquely and hence the given function is not differentiable at origin

but when i tried to find its limit by polar coordinates then its limit came out to b 0

i.e x=r cos theta and y = r sin theta 
then

f(r, thetha) = (sin2 theta) r exp(i theta)

on putting limit r tends to 0 we get 
zero

my query is that if the function is not differentiable at origin then whatever approach we apply its limit should not exist uniquely or finitely 
but here wen i try to solve it by polar approach i m getting 0 ie unqiue and finite limit 
& on the other hand by previous method i found that it depend on parameter m

is there any mistake i am making while solving it by latter method ? please solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about what you're trying to prove.  Your calculation with polar coordinates shows correctly that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} f\left(z\right) = 0$ .  But this merely establishes that $f$ is *continuous* at $z = 0$, not that it's *differentiable* there.  To determine whether it's differentiable you need to establish what happens to $\frac{f\left(z\right) - f\left(0\right)}{z - 0} = \frac{f\left(z\right)}{z}$ as $z\rightarrow 0$ .

If you divide your expression for $f\left(z\right)$ in terms of polar coordinates by $z = r e^{i\theta}$ you're left with $\sin\left(2\theta\right)$ , independent of $r\ .$  This is equal to $1$ for $\theta  = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $0$ for $\theta  = 0$, so there are values of $z$ arbitrarily close to $0$ for which $\frac{f\left(z\right)}{z} = 1$ and others for which $\frac{f\left(z\right)}{z} = 0$. It therefore can't have a limit as $z\rightarrow 0$ , and consequently $f$ is not differentiable at $z= 0$ .

Comment: no no that i understood very well ..m query is about the limit ...wen i try to solve it with the help of polar coordinates ...limit exists and equal to zero ...but wen i try to solve it with an alternative approach like along different path ...it depends on parameter m n hence the limit doesnt exist in this case ....so why is this difference ? if the limit doesnt exist then no matter whatever approach u go with it will never exist

Comment: ooops! my bad ...i just skipped a step in calculation ....how could i do such silly mistakes .....totally agree with u ....thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not depend on a parameter !

Since $|Im(z^2)| \le |z|^2=|z|^2$, we get

$|f(z)| \le |z|$ for all $z $.